# just capture the text and remove the email with a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that removes me in my text `email: toto@toto.com.`

**example:** `I ​​request information on your project email: toto@free.fr` 
So I did this that captures me "email: toto@toto.com"

```
message ="I ​​request information on your project email. toto@free.fr"
message.gsub!("/(email: [-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$)/i")
```

it returns me nothing, and I wish there was just in the message text.

thanks

Comment: In your example message there is no `email :` only `email.` is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- You are looking for `"email: ..."`, but you message has `"email. ..."`.
- You use [`gsub!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21), with one parameter, which is not the classic use case, and returns an `Enumerator`. The classic use case expects a second parameter, which indicates to what you want to substitute the found matches:

  > Performs the substitutions of String#gsub in place, returning str, or
  >   nil if no substitutions were performed. **If no block and no replacement
  >   is given, an enumerator is returned instead**.
- You pass a string to the `gsub!` - `"/(email: [-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$)/i"`, which is *different* than sending a regex. To pass a regex, you need to drop the quotes around it: `/(email: [-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$)/i`

So a fix to your code would look like this:

```
message ="I ​​request information on your project email: toto@free.fr"
message.gsub!(/(email: [-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$)/i, '')
# => "I ​​request information on your project "
```

Also note I changed your code to use [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) instead of `gsub!`, since `gsub!` changes the underlying string, instead of creating a new one, and unless you have a good reason to do that, it is not encouraged to mutate the input arguments...

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This should work for both uppercase, lowercase and emails appear in the middle of the string.

```
email = /[A-Za-z]{5}:\s[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/

s = "I request information on your project email: toto@free.fr"
s.match(email).pre_match     #=> "I request information on your project "

s2 = "This email: blah@bLAH.com is in the middle"
s2.match(email).pre_match    #=> "This "
s2.match(email).post_match   #=> " is in the middle"
```

But there are more cases not covered e.g. `email:` followed by many spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the email from the text use [String#sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-sub)

```
message = "I ​​request information on your project email. toto@free.fr"
message.sub!(/[A-Za-z]{5}:\s[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/, '')
# => "I ​​request information on your project "
```

Comment: I just want to get the text and not email: toto@toto.com